# Условие для Select sql

Tags: sql

Как сделать условие для SELECT в SQL?

Comment: Какое именно условие? Будьте конкретнее - в SELECT может быть куча условий в разных местах - условия связывания, предфильтрации, постфильтрации, в выражениях (практически в любой кляузе)...

Comment: Что вы хотите выбрать, где и откуда?.. есть разные диалекты SQL. У Мускула и Оракла,с Постгресом могут отличаться некоторые аспекты.

Comment: Конкретизируйте и дополните свой вопрос иначе его вскоре закроют как слишком общий

Comment: почитайте справку о том как задавать вопросы, какие вопросы можно задавать, а какие не очень приветствуются и как все это нужно оформлять. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взято отсюда [metanit](http://metanit.com/sql/sqlserver/4.5.php):
Для фильтрации в команде SELECT применяется оператор WHERE. После этого оператора ставится условие, которому должна соответствовать строка:

```
WHERE условие
```

Если условие истинно, то строка попадает в результирующую выборку. В качестве можно использовать операции сравнения. Эти операции сравнивают два выражения. В T-SQL можно применять следующие операции сравнения:

```
=: сравнение на равенство (в отличие от си-подобных языков в T-SQL для сравнения на равенство используется один знак равно)

<>: сравнение на неравенство

<: меньше чем

>: больше чем

!<: не меньше чем

!>: не больше чем

<=: меньше чем или равно

>=: больше чем или равно
```